# Install Amazon pay extension from admin panel in magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3

[image]

Readiness check fails while installing Amazon pay module in **Magento CE 2.2.3**

for checking cron scripts i have changed the code in

> C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Environment.php

**Uncomment this**

```
    $setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();
    $updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();
```

**and add this**

```
    $setupCheck = ['success' => 1];
    $updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];
```

the above code is to avoid check cron.

PHP settings check and PHP extensions check are failed
**XAMPP v3.2.2 php version 7.0.27**

How do i fix this and install any extension from admin page ?

Comment: Your screen shot is showing that you have issue in php setting.Some php extension is enabled at your system.Please click on `Show Detail` and you can see the error.

Comment: Show Detail is empty

Answer (score 1):

You should check below links

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/fix-php-settings-check-error-in-magento-2-0-installation-on-localhost/

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html

These links will help you.

Comment: I have installed M 2.2.3 it successfully. This above screenshot error is from after installation, navigate to admin->system->tools->websetup wizard->extension manager->review and install